# Uninitialized string

Tags: php

I've got this error:

**Notice: Uninitialized string offset: -1 in App.php on line 8**

line 8 is the second line below:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if(!empty($uri) && $uri[-1] === "/"){
      header('Location: '. substr($uri, 0, -1));
      header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
      exit();
    }
```

I just want to redirect to index.php if uri is index.php/

My php version is 7.0.30, this code should work (I took it from php tutorial)

Oh and of course, the header location not working, if I gonna index.php/ it doesn't redirect me.

Comment: What is `$uri[-1]`?

Comment: why would your array have a negative index? `var_dump($uri); exit;` to see what you actually have

Comment: @delboy It's not an array, it's a string.

Comment: @Script47 $uri[-1] is the last char of $uri. So if it's "/" it's mean url end with "/" so I remove it

Answer (score 2):

Negative offsets are supported since PHP **7.1**, as clearly noted in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr).

Comment: Ok, so it explains why he got the error. But this answer has no solution for him? ... hmm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr($uri, -1)` to get the same result in versions of PHP below 7.1.

Indeed, you even use it on the next line!

Answer (score 0):

There is no negative-string-offsets support in PHP 7.0.

You can better check with

```
substr($uri, -1) === "/"
```

when using php 7.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$uri[strlen($uri)-1]` I think.